# what does "Object.assign() does not throw on null or undefined source values" mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I read this on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> "Object.assign() does not throw on null or undefined source values"

When I try it on [`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/bafuyicice/edit?html,js,console), it seems not work.

```js
var obj1 = {p: null};
var obj2 = {p: "new"};

console.log(_.assign(obj1, obj2));
console.log(_.merge(obj1, obj2));
console.log(Object.assign(obj1, obj2));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

can anybody help me to explain why? tks for any reply~

Comment: the result is
 {
  "p": "new"
}
{
  "p": "new"
}
{
  "p": "new"
}
if not assign, it should be 
{
  "p": "new"
}
{
  "p": "new"
}
{
  "p": null
}
???

Answer (score 4):

It just means you can write

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, null));
```

and it will not throw an error. Nothing more. The example you provided works as expected.

Comment: you'are so so kind to answer my first question.
thks for you answer, i misunderstood the source value and target value.